# What is the difference between Table.column_name and just column_name?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I'm doing a db.run then what is the difference between using

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Table.column_name = value
```

and

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE column_name = value
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you are joining several tables, you may refer to columns in the different tables having the same name. Then you must specify the table name or a table alias to differentiate those columns. In your example it makes no difference.

Example:

```sql
SELECT customer.name AS cust_name, company.name as comp_name
FROM
    customer
    LEFT JOIN company
        ON customer.company_id = company.company_id
```

Here there are `name` and `company_id` columns in both tables.

or, using table aliases

```sql
SELECT cust.name AS cust_name, comp.name as comp_name
FROM
    customer cust
    LEFT JOIN company comp
        ON cust.company_id = comp.company_id
```